# Accessing elements in a static array using pointer(arithmetic) in C

Tags: c, arrays

If I have the following code in a function:

```
int A[5][5];
  int i; int j;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
      A[i][j]=i+j;
      printf("%d\n", A[i][j]);
    }
  }
```

This simply prints out the sum of each index. What I want to know is if it's possible to access each index in the static array in a similar fashion to dynamic array. So for example, if I wanted to access A[2][2], can I say:

```
*(A+(2*5+2)*sizeof(int))?
```

I want to perform some matrix operations on statically allocated matrices and I feel like the method used to dereference dynamic matrices would work the best for my purposes. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: That array is not static as you claim.

Comment: The multiplication by sizeof() is unnecessary if the pointer being dereferenced is a pointer-to-int. Pointer arithmetic steps by the size of the type pointed to pointed.

Comment: @dmckee not only is it not necessary, it's wrong. First, it won't do what he's expecting it does, second, you can go over the bound of the array and get into undefined behavior.

Comment: To @EdS.'s point the array is "automatic" or "at file scope" depending on the existence or non-existence of a un-exhibited enclosing function.

Answer (score 4):

That's the way to do it:  `A[i][j]`.

It prints out the sum of the indexes because, well, you set the element `A[i][j]` to the sum of the indexes: `A[i][j] = i+j`.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to access an element using pointer arithmetic.  It's more a question about the way the data is allocated than about the "proper" way to access it.

Comment: @AdamLiss could be, or maybe he's confused that he's getting the sum of the indexes.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I read the statement, "This simply prints out the sum of each index" a bit differently from how you read it. You read it as, "The problem is, this is supposed to print out the array elements, but instead, it prints out the sums of their indices." I read it as, "This is just simple code to show what I mean; it prints out the array elements, which are set to the sums of their indices."

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
*(*(A + 2) + 2)
```

for `A[2][2]`. Pointer arithmetics is done in unit of the pointed type not in unit of `char`.

Of course, the preferred way is to use `A[2][2]` in your program.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I assumed the OP asked the equivalence of `A[2][2]` with explicit pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore `A[2][2]` its not wrong. But he's asking a way to access the elements of `A` using its pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

The subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - you compute an offset of `i` elements (**not bytes**) from `a` and then dereference the result.  For a 2D array, you just apply that definition recursively:

```
a[i][j] == *(a[i] + j) == *(*(a + i) + j)
```

If the array is allocated contiguously, you could also just write `*(a + i * rows + j)`.

When doing pointer arithmetic, the size of the base type is taken into account.  Given a pointer

```
T *p;
```

the expression `p + 1` will evaluate to the address of the next object of type `T`, which is `sizeof T` bytes after `p`.

Note that using pointer arithmetic may not be any faster than using the subscript operator (code up both versions and run them through a profiler to be sure).  It will *definitely* be less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic can be tricky.
You are on the right track, however there are some differences between pointer and normal arithmetic.
For example consider this code

```
int I = 0;
float F = 0;
double D = 0;
int* PI = 0;
float* PF = 0;
double* PD = 0;

cout<<I<<" "<<F<<" "<<D<<" "<<PI<<" "<<PF<<" "<<PD<<endl;
I++;F++;D++;PI++;PF++,PD++;

cout<<I<<" "<<F<<" "<<D<<" "<<PI<<" "<<PF<<" "<<PD<<endl;
cout<<I<<" "<<F<<" "<<D<<" "<<(int)PI<<" "<<(int)PF<<" "<<(int)PD<<endl;
```

If you run it see the output you would see would look something like this (depending on your architecture and compiler)

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0x4 0x4 0x8
1 1 1 4 4 8
```

As you can see the pointer arithmetic is handled **depending on the type of the variable it points to**.

So keep in mind which type of variable you are accessing when working with pointer arithmetic.

Just for the sake of example consider this code too:

```
void* V = 0;

int* IV = (int*)V;
float* FV = (float*)V;
double* DV = (double*)V;

IV++;FV++;DV++;
cout<<IV<<" "<<FV<<" "<<DV<<endl;
```

You will get the output (again depending on your architecture and compiler)

```
0x4 0x4 0x8
```

Remember that the code snippets above are just for demonstration purposes. There are a lot of things **NOT to use** from here.